# WPF Multiple mouse clicking disabling mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mouseevent, contextmenu

I have a problem: I have datagrid and I want to open context menu on left mouse button click. So I create datagrid and template column inside it:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource StageNameCellStyle}"/>
```

Cell style:

```
<Style x:Key="StageNameCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:OpenContextMenuLeftBehavior/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                    <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="1"
                                      Command="{Binding Data.AddReportCommand, Source={StaticResource WindowViewModel}}">
                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource TypicalImageStyle}" Source="../Resources/Images/report_add.png"/>
                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And behavior for it:

```
public class OpenContextMenuLeftBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += OpenContextMenu;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= OpenContextMenu;
    }

    void OpenContextMenu(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) {
            ((FrameworkElement)sender).ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            ((FrameworkElement)sender).ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So, problem is:
When I click many times on that cell, first some clicks is opening menu, but then stop and not firing mouse events at all.
But if I move cursor out of window and return it - it will work again.
Please help me.

Comment: if you remove placement target setter will it work fine?

Comment: @Mikolaytis No, nothing changed.